# 1 service - 2 ctrl - how to bind value of the service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I'm new with AngularJS. I try to make a little explorer game with angularJS

Here is the problem:

When I click on the button, the inventory should be showed. When I console.log the function, I can see the change of the value of showedInventory but the InventoriesCtrl don't.

service

```
angular.module('InventoryService', []) 
.factory('InventoryService', function(){

    var showedInventory = false;

    return{

        getShowInventory: function(){
            console.log('getShowInventory');
            return showedInventory;
        },
        showInventory: function(){
            console.log('showInventory');
            showedInventory = true;
            return showedInventory;
        }

    }
})
```

ctrl 1 & 2

```
App.controller('navigationsCtrl',['$scope', 'InventoryService', function($scope, InventoryService){
$scope.showInventory = function(){
    InventoryService.showInventory();
}}]);

app.controller('InventoriesCtrl',['$scope', 'InventoryService', function($scope, InventoryService){
$scope.showedInventory = InventoryService.getShowInventory();}]);
```

Someone can help me ?     https://jsfiddle.net/s8spyw21/3/
(note the

"INVENTORY !"

shoudn't be showed)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle and I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/dougefresh/ydL81p75/7/

Other than not having your fiddle setup correctly ( you needed to modify html body tag settings to contain `<body ng-app="myApp">`, along with setting up the controllers a little nicer) it comes down to understanding how data binding works specifically with factories. 
You cannot bind to a variable, but you can bind to an accessor, which I think you were trying to do.
In your controller you had the following which ran the function then bound to your scope object, so it never updated

```
$scope.showedInventory = InventoryService.getShowInventory(); // In controller
```

what you needed to do was this:

```
$scope.showedInventory = InventoryService.getShowInventory;
```

that binds the method, not the result. 
Then in your view instead of this:

```
<div ng-show="showedInventory==true">
```

you should have the following, which calls the getter method every digest cycle

```
<div ng-show="showedInventory()==true">
```

and it can actually be shortened to just this

```
<div ng-show="showedInventory()">
```